# Загрузка рекламы Admob

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, admob

Как мне загружать рекламу, чтобы она не тормозила приложение. Я точно знаю, что метод loadAd тормозит загрузку. Что мне сделать, чтобы этого не было ?

```
        object : AsyncTask<Void?, Void?, Void?>() {
            var adRequest: AdRequest? = null
            override fun onPostExecute(aVoid: Void?) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid)
                    mInterstitialAd = InterstitialAd(applicationContext)
                    mInterstitialAd.adUnitId = AD_ID
                    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest)
                    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest)
            }
            override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: Void?): Void? {
                adRequest = if (isPersonalized) {
                    AdRequest.Builder().build()
                } else {
                    extras.putString("npa", "1")
                    AdRequest.Builder()
                        .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter::class.java, extras)
                        .build()
                }
                return null
            }
        }.execute()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Увы но по сути никак, единственное что можно сделать это разнести во времени отображение на экране activity/fragment и вызов loadAd, например отсрочить его на 1 секунду, тормозить в итоге будет так же, но в метриках не будет "долгой загрузки" приложения